# How to get the top record from each set of group

Tags: greatest-n-per-group, oracle-sql-developer

*This question is for Oracle SQL DEV*

What I am trying to accomplish is to pull the top record for each person (last name + First name + Dob), using their most recent travel date. To help illustrate my point, I included a screenshot of two individuals and their travel history. I want my query to pull only one record from each name + dob group using their most recent travel date.

I tried to use the row_number and partition but couldn't gain any traction. Can a more experienced developer/programmer help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following (untested) should work:

```
with partitions as (
  select
    x.*,
    row_number() over (partition by last_name, first_name, dob order by travel_date desc) as r
  from my_table as x
)
select *
from partitions
where r = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked fine